# How do I insert html tags in JS with pug?

Tags: javascript, json, pug, html-preprocessor

When I need to use a JSON-like object in JS with different data in each block  and iterating through that object I make a HTML code via pug.

Let me describe it in code

```
var footerMenu = {
   left: {
      title: "sometitle",
      list: [
         {
         title: "First thing to do",
         text:  "wake up and brush some teeth"
         },

         {
         title: "Second thing to do",
         text:   "start coding"
         },
(...)
```

Problem comes when text withing property `footerMenu.left[0].text` has to be styled with some tags.

I need something like this

```
...... text: "wake up and #[span.color-red brush] some teeth"
```

but, of course pug read that as simple string.

I don't want to write each block manually, how do I save same code structure but apply random tags into my JSON-object with pug ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write the html tags as usually something like:

`text: "wake up and <span class='color-red brush'>some teeth</span>"`

Then in pug you can use [unescaped attributes](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html#unescaped-attributes) like this:

```
.some-class!=footerMenu.left[0].text
```

or using [string interpolation attributes unescaped](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html#string-interpolation-unescaped)

```
.some-class !{footerMenu.left[0].text}
```

Comment: thx, that solved my issue. but still raised another question. how do i keep pug syntax in thos JSON object properties ? Like text: "wake up and #[span assad] ..." because there might be a need in that in future

Comment: @Anton sorry don't understand what you mean.

Comment: in your answer you are using casual html tags syntax - <span> </span>, in pug you can only type - span [some text]. So how do i use pug syntax in same situation like in my question ?

Comment: but that's a different question, not related to this one, this one is how to use tags in js/json. now do you want to know how to use regular HTML tags in pug files directly. That's what I understood from your comment.Nevertheless it is possible, just look at the docs in https://pugjs.org